# Adobe Fireworks CS4 won't proceed past License Agreement

Tags: license, adobe-fireworks

I've been using Adobe Fireworks CS4 for about 12 months, and every time it loads it has asked me to accept the license agreement.  Adobe support did not know how to fix this.

In the last few days, pressing Accept, Cancel, or Decline does nothing at all.

All other programs are functioning fine.  I'm in WinXP SP3, and want to confirm if the Adobe Licensing service is running, but when I open Services.msc, I receive the error:

> One of more ActiveX controls could not be displayed because either:
>
> 1) Your current security settings prohibit running ActiveX controls on this page, or
>   2) You have blocked a publisher of one of the controls.
>
> As a result, the page might not display correctly.